# neural network: why can't I predict y=x*2?

Tags: r, neural-networks

I'm trying to understand some basics of neural nets and am trying to build one that can predict the function $y = 2*x$ in R:

```
library(caret)
library(nnet)

v1 <- 1:1000
v2 <- v1 * 2
df <- data.frame(v1, v2)

mod <- train(v2 ~ v1, data = df, method = "nnet")
predict(mod, df)
```

I end up getting all 1's for the answers. I'm able to predict other, more complex functions using a neural net, but, for some reason, I can't predict this function.

Does anyone happen to know why that might be?

Thank you!

Bill

Comment: The problem was that I was failing to specify the "linout" parameter as TRUE. Thanks to Alex R. for noticing this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify "linout=TRUE" in the nnet, function as the default is logistic output. i.e.:

```
mod <- train(v2 ~ v1, data=df, method="nnet",linout=TRUE)
```